# Php memory profiler - what are <cycle> records?

Tags: php, memory-management, memory-leaks

I started to use [PHP memory profiler](https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-memory-profiler) by Arnaud Le Blanc.

While analyzing the `.out` file in QCacheGrind, I wasn't able to figure out what the `<cycle>` function records are? Can anyone explain these?

Other functions have `location` filled, but these `<cycle nr>` functions have no `location` at all.  Btw, I am not sure why all of them have `todo.php` and not the correct path?

[image]

Comment: @KIKOSoftware https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-memory-profiler